# Gulp.src is ignoring subdirectories

Tags: javascript, gulp

I've got my gulpfile doing some JS work as follows:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/javascripts'))
        .on('error', handleErrors);
});
```

My directory structure is something like this:

```
- src
-- js
--- controllers
---- Home.js
--- main.js
```

main.js is getting snagged, but Home.js is completely ignored. If I throw more files in the `src/js/` directory, they get included too. Somethings up with my subfolders. Any advice?